# Android Application Crash on button event

Tags: android, crash

I am trying to make a simple android application that can add two numbers, but it is crashing as soon as I press on add button.Please find the code below.The emulator uses 300 MB RAM

I have two editboxes in which numbers are being inputted and their sum is being displayed on third input box by tapping on add button

```
package example.sample;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

                EditText E1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText E2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText E3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                String s=E1.toString();
                String m=E2.toString();
            //  String k="sud";
                int num1=Integer.parseInt(s);
                int num2=Integer.parseInt(m);
                int num3 =num1+num2;
                String f=Integer.toString(num3);
                E3.setText(f);


        }

      });




}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
String s=E1.toString();
String m=E2.toString();
```

to

```
String s=E1.getText().toString();
String m=E2.getText().toString();
```

for getting text from EditText's on Button Click. currently you are trying to parse View's as Integer

Comment: I would also suggest some error checking with a `try/catch` or something to prevent from trying to parse a non-`int`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s=E1.getText().toString();
String m=E2.getText().toString();
```

you are not performing addition operation on numbers. That is why your app is crashing.